# WordML Image Size

Tags: xml, image-processing, ms-word, wordml

I am trying to generate an image with WordML.  Yes, it is my only option.  I am using the following code:

```
<w:pict>
<v:shapetype id="_x0000_t75" coordsize="21600,21600" o:spt="75" o:preferrelative="t" path="m@4@5l@4@11@9@11@9@5xe" filled="f" stroked="f">
<v:stroke joinstyle="miter"/>
<v:formulas>
<v:f eqn="if lineDrawn pixelLineWidth 0"/>
<v:f eqn="sum @0 1 0"/>
<v:f eqn="sum 0 0 @1"/>
<v:f eqn="prod @2 1 2"/>
<v:f eqn="prod @3 21600 pixelWidth"/>
<v:f eqn="prod @3 21600 pixelHeight"/>
<v:f eqn="sum @0 0 1"/>
<v:f eqn="prod @6 1 2"/>
<v:f eqn="prod @7 21600 pixelWidth"/>
<v:f eqn="sum @8 21600 0"/>
<v:f eqn="prod @7 21600 pixelHeight"/>
<v:f eqn="sum @10 21600 0"/>
</v:formulas>
<v:path o:extrusionok="f" gradientshapeok="t" o:connecttype="rect"/>
<o:lock v:ext="edit" aspectratio="t"/>
</v:shapetype><w:binData w:name="wordml://01000001.gif">
[Image Data]
</w:binData>
<v:shape id="_x0000_s1026" type="#_x0000_t75" style="position:absolute;margin-left:0;margin-top:0;width:91.5pt;height:43.5pt;z-index:-1" wrapcoords="-177 0 -177 21228 21600 21228 21600 0 -177 0">
<v:imagedata src="wordml://01000001.gif" o:title="JGerow_Small "/>
<w10:wrap type="tight"/>
</v:shape>
</w:pict>
</w:p>
```

The problem is, when the document generates, the image is squashed horizontally in a rather ugly manner.

What attribute can I change to eliminate this image squashing?

![Picutre of Image Squash (The signature, as you can see, is squashed horizontally)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYgFo.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it to the size I want.  Here are the changes I made for those curious and trying to make similar changes.

```
<w:pict>
<v:shapetype id="_x0000_t75" coordsize="**20000,41600**" o:spt="75" o:preferrelative="t" path="m@4@5l@4@11@9@11@9@5xe" filled="f" stroked="f">
<v:stroke joinstyle="miter"/><v:formulas>
<v:f eqn="if lineDrawn pixelLineWidth 0"/>
<v:f eqn="sum @0 1 0"/>
<v:f eqn="sum 0 0 @1"/>
<v:f eqn="prod @2 1 2"/>
<v:f eqn="prod @3 **41600** pixelWidth"/>
<v:f eqn="prod @3 **20000** pixelHeight"/>
<v:f eqn="sum @0 0 1"/>
<v:f eqn="prod @6 1 2"/>
<v:f eqn="prod @7 **41600** pixelWidth"/>
<v:f eqn="sum @8 21600 0"/>
<v:f eqn="prod @7 **20000** pixelHeight"/>
<v:f eqn="sum @10 **20000** 0"/>
</v:formulas>
<v:path o:extrusionok="f" gradientshapeok="t" o:connecttype="rect"/>
<o:lock v:ext="edit" aspectratio="t"/>
</v:shapetype>
<w:binData w:name="wordml://01000001.gif">
[Image Data]
</w:binData>
<v:shape id="_x0000_s1026" type="#_x0000_t75" style="position:absolute;margin-left:0;margin-top:0;width:191.5pt;height:40pt;z-index:-1" wrapcoords="-177 0 -177 21228 **41600 41228 41600** 0 -177 0">
<v:imagedata src="wordml://01000001.gif" o:title="JGerow_Small "/>
<w10:wrap type="tight"/>
</v:shape>
</w:pict>
</w:p>
```

Comment: could you plz give me the article link where I can find how to show image with custom height width in OOXML?